# How to get shared files from Windows on Android through the Internet?

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

I have a Wi-Fi router in the home. My PC constantly connected to the router, and it's IPv4 is 192.168.0.100 (static). Also I always know a global IPv4 of the router (NAT is disabled). On the PC I have a shared folder through the SMB protocol.

I have an android device. I want to get access to the shared folder on my android device, when it is NOT connected to the my Wi-Fi (for example in the office or university). I also can connect to my VPN server from my Laptop (it is not a PC) in such places.

Now, what I decided to do? I decided to up the OpenVPN server on my PC, and connect to it from my android device through the Internet (Of course when I'm not at home) to emulate the connection to my Wi-Fi local network.

If the VPN server is setup to the TAP mode, I can get access to the folder on my Laptop, when I connected to the VPN. If TUN - no. But access to the folder on the Laptop isn't interesting me, I want to get access on my android device, but it doesn't support TAP mode. In TUN mode I can connect to the VPN, but cannot get access to the folder (on a Laptop and on Android). So the question is - how to activate the support of TAP mode on the android OR may be you know another solutions instead of using VPN?